# Well seen/ Good viewed or other

Tags: phrase-request

If I want to congratulate someone for a good observation, which sentence should I apply?

> - Well seen
> - Good viewed

or something else?

Comment: "Good observation", as you've expressed it.

Comment: *Well spotted* is idomatic.

Comment: *(That's a) good catch* is also common.

Comment: Probably the most common congratulatory form for most contexts would be [**Well spotted!**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22well+spotted+said%22)

Answer (score 2):

In sports, when congratulating a player on a good observation that resulted in a successful play (for example a quarterback saw an open player in the end zone and was able to recognize the opportunity and complete the pass) I would often hear *good eye*

I've never heard *good viewed* spoken, as it does sound unnatural and *well seen* seems a little formal and unnatural.